Local instance of SQL Server 2022 won't start: error 1067
I have a user that has installed SQL Server 2022 on his local machine to do testing with our product, however each time he tries to start it we get a 1067 error. We have tried this with 2019 and had the same result.
Here's the data I can give:
-Windows 11 Enterprise
-Sector size confirmed as 4096
-Logon is set to local service account
-Event viewer shows the following:
ERROR: The SQL configuration for SQL is inaccessible or invalid.
WARNING: The configuration of the SQL instance SQL2022_WPE is not valid.
Any help is appreciated here. While I have no issues with most things, SQL is not my forte. If I recall I also tried to look at the SQL log itself but it was all Greek to me.
